# Regex, capture one or more 6-digit numbers AFTER specific pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

my first question, so bear with me should anything no quite right. (I have read all topics suggested after entering title, but still no luck)

In words I need to capture all (i.e. one or more) 6-digits numbers **following** after specific keyword (here: "Customer\s"), which begins with 14 or 15

Input string:

> Part Numbe
>
> **Customer** PO
>
> Description
>
> Cust Part No: 325386
>
> EB011036 // 175663/**147667**/8 ECK
>
> 5500003766 / **148266** -
>
> WALK

between the start keyword to look after, and the following suitable 6 digit pattern any signs can be placed.

What I have come up so far:
Since the string can contain return, new lines etc.
I set the (?s) flag before:

Then a positive lookbehind:

```
(?s)(?<=Customer )
```

followed by

```
.+?
```

and then

```
(\D(1(4|5)\d{4})\D)+
```

So the whole expression:

```
(?<=Customer ).*?(\D(1(4|5)\d{4})\D)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/FEKwcY/1

But this only finds the first instance (147667) after **Customer**, not the second or more following.
If I change the wildcard between the groups to gready, it will find the last one, but not the first possible one.

Having played around further I added an alternation in the pos. lookbehind group:

```
(?s)(?<=Customer |\D\d{6}\D).*?(\D(1(4|5)\d{4})\D)+
```

This in fact find the two, but I am afraid, that this will also find **before** the **Customer** keyword.

Comment: Would the following work in your application/regex flavor? [`(?:^.*?\bCustomer\b|\G(?!^)).*?\b\K1[45]\d{4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rni3Ts/1)

Comment: Hi JvdV , wow, that's an amazing one. Have to understand that. But it looks promising. I am using this with Powershell and it seems that most of constructions for PCRE2 flavor do work with Powershell regex class.

Comment: No, Powershell uses .NET regex flavor and it does not support `\K`.

Comment: @JvdV In .NET you can use a capture group `(?:^.*?\bCustomer\b|\G(?!^)).*?\b(1[45]\d{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/JhfG4T/1

Comment: That is nice @Thefourthbird, feel free to answer the question.

Comment: @JvdV It is your pattern, I only changed it to a group so you can post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this is more of a communal given answer as both @WiktorStribiżew and @TheFourthBird had relevant contributions that lead to the following pattern that should work in PowerShell's .Net regex flavor:

```
(?:^.*?\bCustomer\b|\G(?!^)).*?\b(1[45]\d{4})\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKiKay/1).

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `^.*?\bCustomer\b` - Start string anchor followed by 0+ characters (lazy) upto "Customer" inside word-boundaries.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\G(?!^)` - Assert position at position of previous match and explicitly avoid to match the start of the string.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `.*?\b` - 0+ Characters (lazy) upto a word-boundary.
- `(1[45]\d{4})` - A capture group that start a substring with a 1 followed by either a 4 or 5 and 4 other random digits.
- `\b` - Another word-boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```cs
(?s)(?<=\bCustomer\b.*?)\b1[45]\d{4}\b
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbCustomer%5cb.*%3f%29%5cb1%5b45%5d%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=Part+Numbe%0d%0a%0d%0aCustomer+PO%0d%0a%0d%0aDescription%0d%0a%0d%0aCust+Part+No%3a+325386%0d%0a%0d%0aEB011036+%2f%2f+175663%2f147667%2f8+ECK%0d%0a5500003766+%2f+148266+-%0d%0a%0d%0aWALK). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline modifier flag
- `(?<=\bCustomer\b.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Customer` as a whole word and then any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `1` - a `1` char
- `[45]` - `4` or `5`
- `\d{4}` - any four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

PS demo:

```js
PS C:\Users\admin> $s = "Part Number`r`n`r`nCustomer PO`r`n`r`nDescription`r`n`r`nCust Part No: 325386`r`n`r`nEB011036 // 175663/147667/8 ECK`r`n5500003766 / 148266 -`r`n`r`nWALK"
PS C:\Users\admin> Select-String '(?s)(?<=\bCustomer\b.*?)\b1[45]\d{4}\b' -input $s -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches.value}
147667
148266
```

Comment: A non-fixed width positive lookbehind! Great =)